# vaadin TreeTable put tree column in second column

Tags: vaadin

How can I move the tree column in first column of a TreeTable to the second column of the table? When I try moving column 1 to coumn 2 only the contents - not the tree structure - are moved.
Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This put triangles in the second column:

```
treeTable.setHierarchyColumn( NAME_PROPERTY );
```

The NAME_PROPERTY is the second column's property ID.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was after